# HTML data parsing from DIV container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I am pretty new to Web Development this might be an easy question.

In my HTML file I use the form method GET to parse data with the URL (it must be done this way, cannot be changed).

In this html there is a Text Field.

```
<div class="form-group {*if $ERROR_BEMERKUNG*has-error*/if*}">
     <label for="text-comment">Bemerkung</label>
     <textarea name="text-comment" id="text-comment" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="{$TRANSLATE.USERDATA.BEMERKUNG|default:'USERDATA.BEMERKUNG'}">{$COMMENT}</textarea>
</div>
```

How can I get the inside of this textfield, whatever is written in it afterwards, into my GET method? Hardcoded it works that way, but I don't know how I can get the value out of the div.

`<input type="hidden" id="bemerkungen" name="bemerkungen" value= "TEST" />`

EDIT: I didn't have to do anything for the textarea, it got parsed correctly.

But I have another div with a number field.

```
<div class="width115 left form-group has-feedback">
        <span id="personen"> Anzahl Personen </span> 
        <input class="btn-input-wrapper" id="personen" type="number" min="1" value="1"/>
</div>
```

The value out of there is never parsed.

Comment: you can enclosed all the text in different div with the name or id.then you can parse it.

Comment: You must parse `{$COMMENT}` first. But if you do not know what's inside, than you out of luck

Comment: @Justinas *"than you out of luck"* .... that is ridiculous and whatever value is genertaed server side is easily obtained using script

Comment: As the {$COMMENT} comes from the formular and should be filled I should know it, right? But how do I parse it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what higher level problem are you trying to solve? User can easily change any part of the existing text also

Comment: @charlietfl OP does form submission to server, server responds with random text in HTML that is later parsed and replaced with `{$COMMENT}`. How do you know what's inside `{$COMMENT}` that only server knows?

Comment: @Justinas that value can be easily obtained on page load

Comment: If you just delete the {$COMMENT} (I just copied that div as I should) does it recognize whats inside the textarea? The user is filling the textarea and is going to the next page.

Comment: Everything worked with the textarea, edited for another problem with another div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by textfield  you mean textarea, here's your answer:

**All details you have in w3schools:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_form.asp

**Example:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_form

When you send example, it will show you generated GET link with textarea value.

You missing `form="usrform"` part tho, but it should work if you keep everything between `<form>` tags.

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable on Stackoverflow. Links should only be used to support what actually exists in the answer. Note that links rot and if they are no longer valid your answer is completely useless ... not to mention that answers should be self contained

Comment: I'm not missing the form tag, I just didn't want to copy the whole code block as it would have been too big. The input type is inside the form tag. I just need the value from the div :)

Comment: So I am confused what are you trying to achieve. When you submit form it puts all your data into your GET method (generate link with all data). What do you need to do then?

Comment: It actually did, I didn't see that. But I also got a checkbox in another div that gets only set when it's marked (I don't know if that is problematic, I have to ask first) and a number field <div class="width115 left form-group has-feedback">
            <span id="personen"> Anzahl Personen </span> 
            <input class="btn-input-wrapper" id="personen" type="number" min="1" value="1"/>
    </div>

The value of that field is never passed

Comment: Checkbox sends value only if are checked. In than numberic input you dont have name="yourname", thats why its not getting send.

Comment: @RaV These are not w3c links. These are links to w3schools, which is not affiliated in any way with the W3C.